# Unable to paginate EMR cluster using boto

Tags: python, pagination, boto, emr

I have about 55 EMR clusters (all of them were terminated) and have been trying to retrieve the entire 55 EMR clusters using the **list_clusters** method in **boto**. I've been searching for examples about paginating the number of result set from boto but couldn't find any examples. Given this statement:

```
emr_object.list_clusters(cluster_states=["TERMINATED"], marker="what_should_i_use_here").clusters
```

I kept getting **InvalidRequestException** error:

```
boto.exception.EmrResponseError: EmrResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-03-31">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidRequestException</Code>
    <Message>Marker 'what_should_i_use_here' is not valid.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>555b91bd-c122-11e3-8e31-abc75abdb39d</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

What should I provide in **marker** param so that I can properly paginate the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tried with

```
emr_object.describe_jobflows(states=["TERMINATED"])
```

and it works! This method returns all the clusters.

Comment: FYI this method is deprecated and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in None the first time round.

If the ClusterListResult you get back has a marker attribute then you can pass that in later, e.g.

```
m=None
while True:
    try:
        cluster_list_result=emr_object.describe_jobflows(states=['TERMINATED'], marker=m)
        .... Do whatever with cluster_list_result.clusters
        m=cluster_list_result.marker  # See if there are more
    except AttributeError:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. This might come on handy.